# Hyper-V vSwitch issue

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2016

I have built a 2016 server running Hyper-V, 1 NIC for data and 4 others for iSCSI.  I have setup a vswitch (no VLANs) but when I point the switch to the data network card it kills my server.  I have to remote in via iDRAC to disconnect the vswitch from that particular NIC and point it to another NIC to power it back up.  The NIC drivers are the latest versions and there doesn't seem to be a great deal of comment on the WWW about this issue or much within the KBs.  Has anybody else encountered and more importantly resolved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The vSwitch NIC requires the IP address that was previously assigned to the data NIC which then deals with all of the traffic.  This is contrary to thinking that the data NIC passes the data to the vSwitch.